# Find equation of ellipse $(x-u)^t A(x-u)=9$ where $u=(2,1)^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find equation of ellipse $(x-u)^t A(x-u)=9$ where $u=(2,1)^t$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}9& 2\\ 2 & 6\\\end{pmatrix}$

I computed the eigenvalues as $(5,10)$ and a matrix $Q=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2\\-2&1\\\end{pmatrix}$ with diagonal $D=\begin{pmatrix}10&0\\0&5\\\end{pmatrix}$

I know the equation of an ellipse centered at the origin is $(\frac{x}{a})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2=1$

Where $a,b$ are the half lengths of the major and minor axes respectably.

I know that $A=QDQ^{t}$ since $A$ is symmetric, and I should write something like $(x-u)^{t}QDQ^{t}(x-u)=zDz^{t}=9$ where $z=(x-u)^{t}Q$

What I don't understand is how from this form $zDz^{t}=9$, I can find an ellipse equation.

Comment: The equation $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$ only produces ellipses whose center is the origin and whose axes are vertical and horizontal. In general when you have an ellipse specified by $(x-u)^t A (x-u)$, the ellipse is centered at $u$, the axes point in the directions of the eigenvectors of $A$, and the sizes of the axes are dictated by the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: The question seems a little odd to me.  Since the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $ are both positive, the equation $\ (x-u)^tA(x-u)=9\ $ is *already* the equation of an ellipse.  Perhaps you're expected to expand it out and write it in the form
$$
9x^2+6y^2+4xy+cx+dy=e\  
$$
where $\ c,d,e\ $ are constants whose values I can't be bothered working out.  I'd regard this  as a rather pointless exercise, however, unless there's some followup exercise where you're expected to make use of this expression.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera The solution gives the directions are $(2,1)$ and $(1,-2)$ with half lengths of the axes as $3/\sqrt{5}$ and $3/\sqrt{10}$. This was a follow up to finding the spectral decomposition of $A$.

Comment: @AColoredReptile It wasn't clear to me from the wording of the question that those were the details you were expected to give as the answer. The "directions" are just those of the eigenvectors, which you've already found. You can get the lengths of the semiaxes by writing your equation $\ zDz^t=9\ $ as
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{10}\,z_1}{3}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}\,z_2}{3}\right)^2=1\ .
$$
Is there anything else you'd be required to give in your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial equation is
$$(\mathbf{x-c})^T \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{x-c}) = 9 $$

Consider the change of variables
$$
\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{U}^T (\mathbf{x-c})
$$
with the eigenvalue decomposition
$$
\mathbf{A}=
\mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^T
$$

This change of variable is a translation and a rotation.
In the translated-rotated frame, the curve has a nicer expression
$\mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{z} = 9$ or in expanded form

$$
\frac{z_1^2}{(1/\sqrt{10})^2}+
\frac{z_2^2}{(1/\sqrt{5})^2} = 9
$$
or
$$
\frac{z_1^2}{(3/\sqrt{5})^2} +
\frac{z_2^2}{(3/\sqrt{10})^2} = 1
$$
It is thus a tilted ellipse with semi-major axis $3/\sqrt{5}$ and semi-minor axis $3/\sqrt{10}$. Note that it is better to order the columns of $\mathbf{U}$ in increasing order of eigenvalues.